# Failed to insert data into cnosdb

Tags: database, cnosdb

1. start db

```bash
    cnosdb on  read is  v2.3.0 via  v1.70.0-nightly took 2m25s
    ❯ cargo run -- run --config ./config/config_8902.toml --deployment-mode singleton
        Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.40s
         Running `target\debug\cnosdb.exe run --config ./config/config_8902.toml --deployment-mode singleton`
    ----------
```

2. create table & insert

```bash
    public ❯ create table test(intt double,);
    Query took 0.007 seconds.
    public ❯ insert into test values(now(), 1);
    422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"050001","error_message":"Meta request error: Request meta cluster error: create bucket err: -1 database public attribute invalid!"}
    public ❯
```

Just like the above error report `Meta request error: Request meta cluster error: create bucket err: -1 database public attribute invalid!`, such a low-level problem should not appear in database products. Is there something wrong with my operation?

version:
git cimmit id: `9e9171b0c4ab42ee3746c6538477509da2ec6a16`